# View not resizing if done in the "viewWillAppear" or "viewDidLoad" method

Tags: objective-c, view, uiview, resize

I am developing a game: I need to load the user's score (locally and if internet is available, download it from the server) and resize an UIView based on the value.

The problem is that when the score is loaded locally (calling the "resizeUserBar" from viewWillAppear), no view gets resized. But if the same method ("resizeUserBar") is called after the score gets downloaded from the server, it gets resized properly. I have debugged the frame's values and they are correct in both cases.

Here's the code I am using to resize:

```
CGRect frame = firstBar.frame;
frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, firstBarSpace, frame.size.height);
firstBar.frame = frame;

frame = secondBar.frame;
frame = CGRectMake(firstBar.frame.origin.x + firstBarSpace, frame.origin.y, secondBarSpace, frame.size.height);
secondBar.frame = frame;
```

Autolayout is active on my Storyboard but I'm not using it yet. There are no constraints on the views used in the method above.

Thank you
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Autolayout is active on my Storyboard but I'm not using it yet. There
>   are no constraints on the views used in the method above.

In Xcode 5, if you have Auto Layout turned on but don't set any constraints, the compiler will automatically generate fixed size and position constraints for you at build time.

Turn off Auto Layout and you'll see that your resizing will start to work.  Or, setup some actual constraints.

**Update:**  More information…

[Auto Layout Guide: Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1) on Apple.com

> When you drag out an element from the Object Library and drop it on
>   the Interface Builder canvas, it starts out unconstrained to make it
>   easy to prototype your interface by dragging elements around. If you
>   build and run without adding any constraints to an element, you’ll
>   find that Interface Builder fixes the element’s width and height, and
>   pins its position relative to the top left corner of the superview;
>   this means that resizing the window doesn’t move or resize the
>   elements. To make your interface react correctly to changes in size or
>   orientation, you need to start adding constraints.